# A name for a 'food and drink' tour

Tags: expression-choice

One recent trend in Europe  when choosing  a tour or a short holiday is to organise it with the main purpose to go to places where you can taste fine wines and enjoy good food ( especially local and fresh). Is there a proper name  for this sort of tour?

Comment: "Food and Drink Tour" is right there in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, Google's hit counter indicates that on the Web today, **culinary tour** and **food and wine tour** both occur more commonly than **gastronomy/gastronomic tour** by an order of magnitude (though the latter variants are by no means rare). Least common is **wine and food tour**.

Comment: You are right but I think that gastronomic or culinary tours refer specifically to food, in the same way as an 'enotour' refers specifically to wine tasting. My understanding is that OP is looking for a name that refers to both experiences of food and wine.

Comment: @Josh61 - There is clearly some room for subjectivity regarding what is implied by *gastronomic / culinary tours*; but to the extent that fine wines are much more likely to be offered in venues that also offer gourmet-standard food than in cafés or other places that offer only everyday fare, I would regard all the terms I mentioned in my posting as being effectively synonymous.

Comment: Enogastronomic: http://italianfoodandbeverage.blogspot.it/2010/11/mean-of-enogastronomic.html

Answer (score 0):

Gastronomic tour. Or gastronomy tour.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the common definition is **wine and food tours**:

*Wine and food tourism* has become a  popular expression in the recent years as suggested by [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wine%20and%20food%20tourism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,wine%20and%20food%20tourism;,c0).